# Laravel | Использование Auth в шаблонах

Tags: laravel, auth

У меня есть шаблон `layout.blade.php`. Он является родительским и в нем есть "окно пользователя". Там отображается его изображение и логин. Возникла проблема, когда я в шаблоне пытаюсь сделать:

```
@if(Auth::check())
    <div class="avatar avatar-sm">
        <img src="{{$user->privilege}}"
             class="rounded-circle"
             alt="">
    </div>
@else
    <div class="avatar avatar-sm">
        <img src="/media/unknown-user.png"
             class="rounded-circle"
             alt="">
    </div>
@endif
```

`Auth::check()` просто не срабатывает. А если я в `AppServiceProvider` добавлю `view()->share('check', Auth::check())`, то мне выдает `false`, ХОТЯ Я НАХОЖУСЬ НА СТРАНИЦЕ `/home`, где вывожу данные этого самого пользователя.

Вообще не понимаю, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так решил проблему.

```
@php
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
@endphp

@if(Auth::check())
    <div class="avatar avatar-sm">
        <img src="{{Auth::user()->image}}"
             class="rounded-circle"
             alt="">
    </div>
@else
    <div class="avatar avatar-sm">
        <img src="/media/unknown-user.png"
             class="rounded-circle"
             alt="">
    </div>
@endif
```

Не додумался сразу подключить класс.

Comment: Не обязательно использовать `use ....` Достаточно поставить \ перед классом `@if(\Auth::check())`
....
`@endif`

Answer (score 1):

есть директива `@auth`

```
@auth
// Пользователь аутентифицирован
@endauth
@guest
// Пользователь не аутентифицирован
@endguest
```